# Magento: Payment Transaction Failed Reminder SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found

Tags: magento, payment

I got this error while placing an order with payment option Authorize.net.

```
Reason
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'field list' 
Checkout Type
onepage 
Shipping Method:
Shipping Option 
Payment Method:
Credit Card (Authorize.net)
```

Is this a Authorize.net payment method's issue or a Database issue ,may be missing any field.

I can not guess from the reason as is says "Unknown columns" but it shows empty, So i can not guess which column is missing in which table.

Any help would be thankful

---

Another Payment Transaction Failed Reminder

here is the exception log

```
ERR (3): 
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'field list'' in /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `cu...', Array)
#4 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(337): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `cu...', Array)
#5 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `cu...', Array)
#6 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1215): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('customer_entity', Array)
#7 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1012): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_processSaveData(Array)
#8 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
#9 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(150): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#10 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(183): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#11 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(238): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#12 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(742): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#13 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(499): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#14 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#15 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(253): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#16 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(340): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#18 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/app/Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /chroot/home/abc/sitename.com/html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20
```

Comment: I guess it is a bug in magento core. Which magento version do you use? Do you get this error each time when you place order via Authorize.NET?

Answer (score 0):

I'd first recommend running the Magento DB repair tool to see if you have any botched database tables. If not, try turning on the error log in Magento and see if you can get more detail on the query (or at least where in the stack it is generated).

If you get really desperate, turn on query logging in MySQL and take a look at the query directly to see what's going wrong.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe